# Python, .append() and an AttributeError

Tags: python, append, attributeerror

I am trying to write a blackjack program, but when I try to send a message from my deck object to another object that uses .append(), I keep getting an AttributeError: object has no 'append'

Here's what code I think is relevant:

```
class Deck(Hand):

    def deal(self, players, per_hand= 1):
        for rounds in range(per_hand):
            for hand in players:
                if self.hand:
                    top_card = self.hand[0]
                    self.give(top_card,hand)
```

The players parameter is a tuple of objects I instantiated using:

```
class Bj_player(Player,Hand):

    def __init__(self,name,score= 0,status= None):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        self.status = status
        self.hand = Hand()
```

the Player base class has nothing in it but a few inputs from the user.  Is the above where I'm getting it wrong?

```
class Hand(object):
"""a hand of cards"""


    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []

    def add(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)


    def give(self,card,other_hand):
        if self.hand:
            self.hand.remove(card)
            other_hand.add(card)
        else:
            print("EMPTY ALREADY. COULD NOT GIVE")
```

I took out the **str** part to cut it down.  The error I'm getting is this:

```
 line 44, in add
    self.hand.append(card)
    AttributeError: 'Hand' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I'm pretty new so the more simply explained the better.  Thanks.

Also, just in case it's helpful, here's how I'm starting things out:

```
deck = Deck() #populated and all that other stuff

total_players = Player.ask_number("How many players will there be? (1-6): ",1,6)
for player in range(total_players):
    name = input("What is the player's name? ")
    x = Bj_player(name)
    roster.append(x)

deck.deal(roster,2) #error =(
```

Comment: This code just defines the classes, it doesn't use them.  This looks okay.  You'll need to post the part of the code where you actually use these classes.  Somewhere your `Hand` object's `hand` attribute is being set to another `Hand` object.

Comment: What you have should work. At some stage you are changing `self.hand` from a list to a `Hand` object.

Comment: @Levon: I thought about it too, but I think he'd get different errors, it's probably just a pasting misshap.

Comment: Edited to show more code.  Thanks for helping guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
        self.hand = Hand()
```

within the `Bj_player` class. That makes the `self.hand` variable a `Hand` instance, rather than a list as it should be. `roster` is a list of these `BJ_player` instances, so when you call `deck.deal(roster)`, and within the function it says `for hand in players`, each `hand` object will be one of these `Bj_player` instances.

The best way to solve this is for `Bj_player` *not* to inherit from `hand`. (Indeed, it's not clear why you have it inherit from `Player`, or what useful functionality the `Player` class provides). Instead, have `Bj_player` be its own class (perhaps named `Player` instead- less confusing) and change the line

```
    for hand in players:
        if self.hand:
            top_card = self.hand[0]
            self.give(top_card,hand)
```

to

```
    for player in players:
        if self.hand:
            top_card = self.hand[0]
            self.give(top_card,player.hand)
```

A separate note: if you changed `self.hand` to `self.cards`, it would make things a *lot* clearer!

Comment: Yes, the main problem here is Bj_player having a .hand attribute (as a Hand instance), and at the same subclassing from Hand too, which has a .hand attribute as a list.  Either the class hierarchy is wrong, or one of the two attributes needs renaming.

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
a=[1,2,3]
a.append(4)
```

will produce:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
```

but `a=a.append(4)` will return **NonType** object. This object can't be processed.

So will get the **Attribute Error**

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that your variables are all "hand" (lowercase) and not "Hand" (uppercase). If you look at the error, the error is saying that "Hand" (uppercase) has no attribute append. So at some point you either try to append something to the the Hand class, or you set the variable hand to the class Hand. (Note the upper and lowercase of each). Common mistake, it happens to all of us. Happy coding!

Comment: None of his variables are Hand (uppercase) - that message is saying that one of his variables is an instance of the 'Hand' class, which indeed does not have an .append() method.